# Codeigniter : How to detect the first row of a query result

Tags: codeigniter

My `view`is like below.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php 
        foreach($news_data as $nws){
    ?>
    <div class="item **If this is the first row, then echo active**"> 
        <div class="col-md-12 news-item" style="padding-left: 0;">
            <p><?php echo $nws->news_desc; ?></p>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**Model:**

```
function get_news_update()
{
    $this->db->select('news_desc');
    $this->db->from('news');
    $this->db->where('stat', '1');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Please see the `<div class="item`. If it is the first row of `query result`, then it will be `item active`.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your updated code

```
       <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php 
            $i = 0;
            foreach($news_data as $nws){
             // it should be $i. not $i%2 right ?
             if($i == 0) 
            {
                $class="item active";
             }
              else
{
$class = "item";
}
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $class;  ?>"> 
            <div class="col-md-12 news-item" style="padding-left: 0;">
                <p><?php echo $nws->news_desc; ?></p>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please modify `$i%2 == 0` to `$i == 0` and `$class = 'item active'` It works fine. I've corrected it.

Comment: I have just added % for multiple records like if there is 10 records then 1st will get active and 2nd will get item onward. Any way thanks @Raj

Answer (score 2):

Modify your view like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php 
        foreach($news_data as $key => $nws){
    ?>
    <div class="item <?php echo $key == 0 ? "active":""; ?>"> 
        <div class="col-md-12 news-item" style="padding-left: 0;">
            <p><?php echo $nws->news_desc; ?></p>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Taha, Thanks for the simple idea. Your code is probably the simplest and less. I am using your code.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge,You are looking for below code.Please let me know if its not working.

```
function get_news_update()
{
    $this->db->select('news_desc');
    $this->db->from('news');
    $this->db->where('stat', '1');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->first_row();
}
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, I just need to detect the first row while displaying the first item. Not the first row only. Anyway, Dhanyabad...

Answer (score 0):

You can use row() function, which return always the first result.
Model.php

```
function get_news_update(){
  $this->db->select('news_desc');
  $this->db->from('news');
  $this->db->where('stat', '1');
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
  $query = $this->db->get();

   //check if exist
  if (isset($query->row())){
        return $query->row();
  }
}
```

For more informations you will find [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows)

View.php

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item **If this is the first row, then echo active**"> 
        <div class="col-md-12 news-item" style="padding-left: 0;">
            <p><?php echo $nws->news_desc; ?></p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```